# Quadratic form of Kroenecker products of skew-symmetric matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, quadratic-forms, control-theory, graph-laplacian, kronecker-product

I am trying to understand under which conditions on $P=P^\top>0$ , $C=C^\top$, the following quadratic form is zero:

$$
x^\top \left(  
D U^\top \frac{L-L^\top}{2} U \otimes PC
\right)x = 0
$$

where $D$ is diagonal, $U$ is unitary, $\frac{L-L^\top}{2}$ is a skew-symmetric matrix. If needed, $L$ has also zero row-sum (is a Laplacian matrix).  Thanks in advance!!